In unity i have problem with my characters jumping and Y position
I'm creating a game and i'm using raycast and layerMask for jumping and moving but there is problems (as always) when i begin my game after jumping or after some movement with WASD my Y position increases or decreases and i donn't know what to do for like 2 mounths.please helpppp
I tried chat GPT, it couldn't figure it out and neither could I.
Player.cs:
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController characterController;
    private Vector3 moveDir;
    public float speed = 5f;
    private float gravity = 20f;
    private Vector3 gravityDir = Vector3.down; // Başlangıçta yerçekimi aşağıya doğru
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    private Vector3 verticalVelocity;
    private bool isWalking;
    private RootLook rootLook;
    public float gravityRotationSpeed = 5f;
    public float gravityChangeCooldown = 10f;
    private float lastGravityChangeTime = -Mathf.Infinity;

    // LayerMask for surfaces (walls, ceilings, etc.)
    public LayerMask surfaceLayer;

    void Awake()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        rootLook = FindObjectOfType<RootLook>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MoveThePlayer();
        CheckGravityChange();
    }

    void MoveThePlayer()
    {
        Vector3 inputDir = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

        // Get camera directions based on gravity
        Transform cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;
        Vector3 forward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(cameraTransform.forward, gravityDir).normalized;
        Vector3 right = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(cameraTransform.right, gravityDir).normalized;

        // Calculate movement direction
        moveDir = (right * inputDir.x + forward * inputDir.z).normalized * speed;

        // Check if the player is walking
        isWalking = moveDir != Vector3.zero;

        // Apply gravity and vertical movement
        ApplyGravity();

        // Move the character including both movement and vertical velocity (gravity/jumping)
        characterController.Move((moveDir + verticalVelocity) * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void ApplyGravity()
    {
        if (!IsGrounded())
        {
            // Karakter zeminde değilse yerçekimi uygulanır
            verticalVelocity += gravityDir * gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if (verticalVelocity.magnitude < 0.1f)
        {
            // Eğer zemindeyse ve dikey hız çok küçükse, yerçekimini sıfırla
            verticalVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        }

        PlayerJump(); // Karakter zıplayabiliyorsa, zıplama işlemi yapılır
    }


    bool IsGrounded()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, gravityDir);
        RaycastHit hit;

        // Zeminle temas edip etmediğini kontrol et
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1f, surfaceLayer))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    void PlayerJump()
    {
        // Space tuşuna basılıyken ve karakter zemindeyken zıplamaya izin ver
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && IsGrounded())
        {
            verticalVelocity = -gravityDir * jumpForce;
        }
    }

    public bool IsWalking()
    {
        return isWalking;
    }

    void CheckGravityChange()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G) && Time.time - lastGravityChangeTime >= gravityChangeCooldown)
        {
            lastGravityChangeTime = Time.time;

            Vector3 newGravityDir = GetNewGravityDirection();
            newGravityDir.Normalize();

            // Yerçekimi değiştikten sonra hareket yönlerini tekrar hesapla
            StartCoroutine(ChangeGravityAndMovePlayer(newGravityDir));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeGravityAndMovePlayer(Vector3 newGravityDir)
    {
        yield return StartCoroutine(RotatePlayerTowardsGravity(newGravityDir));
        yield return StartCoroutine(RotateCameraTowardsGravity(newGravityDir));

        gravityDir = newGravityDir;
        verticalVelocity = Vector3.zero; // Zıplamadan sonra verticalVelocity'yi sıfırla

        yield return StartCoroutine(DetachFromWalls());

        MoveThePlayer();
    }


    Vector3 GetNewGravityDirection()
    {
        // Yerçekimi yönlerini sıralı olarak değiştir
        if (gravityDir == Vector3.down) return Vector3.left;
        if (gravityDir == Vector3.left) return Vector3.up;
        if (gravityDir == Vector3.up) return Vector3.right;
        return Vector3.down;
    }

    IEnumerator RotatePlayerTowardsGravity(Vector3 newGravityDir)
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.up, -newGravityDir) * transform.rotation;

        // Karakterin düzgün bir şekilde yönlenmesi için yerçekimi yönüne doğru döndürme işlemi
        while (Quaternion.Angle(transform.rotation, targetRotation) > 0.1f)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * gravityRotationSpeed);
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }

    IEnumerator RotateCameraTowardsGravity(Vector3 newGravityDir)
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Camera.main.transform.up, -newGravityDir) * Camera.main.transform.rotation;

        // Kameranın düzgün bir şekilde yönlenmesi için yerçekimi yönüne doğru döndürme işlemi
        while (Quaternion.Angle(Camera.main.transform.rotation, targetRotation) > 0.1f)
        {
            Camera.main.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(Camera.main.transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * gravityRotationSpeed);
            yield return null;
        }

        Camera.main.transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }

    IEnumerator DetachFromWalls()
    {
        float detachTime = 0.2f; // Detach işlemi için zamanı artırdık
        Vector3 detachVelocity = gravityDir * gravity * detachTime;

        float elapsedTime = 0f;
        while (elapsedTime < detachTime)
        {
            characterController.Move(detachVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

}


I've run your code and it seems to work. I couldn't reproduce your issue.
I've only tried to move and jump around then reload the scene via code to "start new game" but it did't affect player behaviour.
Maybe the way you run new game is the key.
However you should try to use debugger like in Visual Studio to trace what is causing unwanted player vertical movement.

what "Maybe the way you run new game is the key." this exactly means?
In my unity i've run my code again after your comment but in my unity same thing happens again.When i'm jumping right after the game starts, after grounding, my Y position becomes negative.
How can i check my unity if the code is correct as you said. Thank you for response i really need and appreciate you help.
